# Pandas: Create a new column that alternate between values in two other columns

Tags: pandas

How can I transform a Dataframe with columns S (start), E (end), V (value)

```
S E V 
1 2 3
2 5 11
5 11 5
```

And transform it to:

```
T V
1 3
2 3
2 11
5 11
5 5
11 5
```

?

This is so that we can plot the data with in such a way the value V (y-axis) is the same throughout the interval.

Edit:

Some are suggesting this is the same as a "how do I use melt()?" question. However the order of the result is important.

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars='V', value_name='T')[['T', 'V']]`

Comment: The trouble with melt is that the order is important. To use melt it seems I need to first create a column from the index so that I resort by row id after melting. It seems that @Nk03 is better since with melt I seem to have to faff with indexes anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or with set_index/stack:

```
df = df.set_index('V').stack().reset_index(-1, drop =True).reset_index(name = 'T')
```

OUTPUT:

```
    V   T
0   3   1
1   3   2
2  11   2
3  11   5
4   5   5
5   5  11
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `melt`

```
df.melt('V')
Out[39]: 
    V variable  value
0   3        S      1
1  11        S      2
2   5        S      5
3   3        E      2
4  11        E      5
5   5        E     11
```

Comment: The order of the result is important.
The best I can do is with melt is:

    df.rename_axis('ix').reset_index().melt(['V','ix'],  value_name='T').sort_values(['ix','variable'], ascending=[True, False])